# IOS 14 DeviceOrientationEvent gets denied right away

Tags: javascript, accelerometer, ios14, motionevent, motion-detection

I am trying to get access to the iPhones Accelerometer. Since iOS 13 You have to ask for Permission in App. I am using IOS 14 and I don't even get an request. It gets denied right away

```
 if(typeof(DeviceMotionEvent) !== 'undifined' && typeof(DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission) === "function"){
// requestAcces()
}

function requestAcces(){
    DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
        .then(permissionState => {
            text(permissionState,100, 100);  // answer is "denied"
            if (permissionState === 'granted') {
            window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', () => {});
            }
        })
        .catch(console.error);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `requestAccess()` function needs to be triggered by the user's action, for example, as a callback function for button `onclick` event. Here is a demo: https://accelerometerdemo.netlify.app

```html
<button onclick="requestAccess()">Get Accelerometer Permissions</button>
```

```js
function requestAccess() {
    DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission().then(permissionState => {
        if (permissionState == 'granted') {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```